# python tkinter button in frame

Tags: python, tkinter

It feels this should be easy but not as much as I would hope.  All I want to do is put a button in a frame.  My code is coloring the frame so I can validate the button is where I want to put it and as you can see, below, my code is not doing what I want/think.  I expect my code to put the radio button inside the yellow frame - not under it.

```
from tkinter import *

class apiMain:

    def main(self):
        master=Tk()

        topframe = Frame(master, bg="Lemon chiffon", width=500, height=50).pack(side = TOP)        

        v = IntVar()
        crbutton = Radiobutton(topframe, text = "change request", variable = v, value = 'cr')
        crbutton.pack(side = LEFT, padx = 10)        

        mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign `topframe` like this:

```
topframe = Frame(master, bg="Lemon chiffon", width=500, height=50).pack(side = TOP)
```

You are essentially writing `topframe = None`, because `pack()` always returns `None`.  Because of this, you're assigning the master of your radio button to `None` which defaults to the main window. Split your code up, so that `topframe` references the actual Frame object:

```
topframe = Frame(master, bg="Lemon chiffon", width=500, height=50)
topframe.pack(side = TOP)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.